# Usage of an CSV import line by line and export as csv again

Tags: powershell, foreach

I will try to explain my problem as good as possible to you all.
Currently I am trying to get some Information of Serial numbers and Manufacturer names of Computers in my Domain.

Here is a gap of my code I'm currently using for this:

```
$computername = import-csv "C:\Daten\pc.csv" | select -ExpandProperty Computername


ForEach ($computer in $computername) 
{
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID

$i = 1
$obj = new-object -type psobject
Foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
    {
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Modell") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.UserFriendlyName -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Serial") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.SerialNumberID -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("MAC-Addresse") -value $mac -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Seriennummer PC") -value $seriennummer_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Modell PC") -value $modell_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | Add-Member -Name ("Computername") -value $computer -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
    $i++   
    $obj | export-csv -path C:\Daten\test.csv
}}
```

My Problem now is that the Export works, but only for the last line in my imported-csv. I also already tried it with Get-Content command.

Here is the exported-csv:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Monitor1 Modell","Monitor1 Serial","Monitor2 Modell","Monitor2 Serial","MAC-Addresse","Seriennummer PC","Modell PC","Computername"
B22W-7 LED,"XYZ123459","B22W-7 LED","XYZ123457","00:00:00:00:00:00","XYZ123456","LIFE1337","COMPUTER2"
```

Would be awesome if you could help me with that.

THANKS in advance,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Issues I see...
Create the new object inside the for loop.
Export to CSV outside your for loop.
Put all $obj in an array, export that.

Possible solution:

```
$computername = import-csv "C:\Daten\pc.csv" | select -ExpandProperty Computername

$items = @()
ForEach ($computer in $computername) 
{
    $Monitors = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID

    $i = 1
    Foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
    {
        $obj = new-object -type psobject
        $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Modell") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.UserFriendlyName -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
        $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Serial") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.SerialNumberID -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
        $obj | add-member -Name ("MAC-Addresse") -value $mac -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
        $obj | add-member -Name ("Seriennummer PC") -value $seriennummer_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
        $obj | add-member -Name ("Modell PC") -value $modell_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
        $obj | Add-Member -Name ("Computername") -value $computer -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
        $i++   
        $items += $obj
    }
}

$items | export-csv -path C:\Daten\test.csv
```

Comment: I have rewritten the code with your solution. Could you take a look on it why it does not work as wished? See in the comments, please. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

With the following tested code you can solve it more easily.

```
import-csv "C:\Daten\pc.csv" `
| select -ExpandProperty Computername `
| ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID `
| Select-Object @{Name = "Monitor Model"; Expression = {[char[]]$_.UserFriendlyName -join ''}},
                @{Name = "Monitor Serial"; Expression = {[char[]]$_.SerialNumberID -join ''}} }  `
| Export-Csv -Path C:\Daten\test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could resolve your problem with the `-Append` Parameter.
So the export would be like this:

```
$obj | export-csv -path C:\Daten\test.csv -Append
```

This way you don't have to move the export outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help so far.

I have seperated my Output into two CSV. It's easier for me.

I now have the Problem that only one Monitor is shown from each Computer but at least two are connected on every Computer here...

Look at the code please:

```
$items = @()
ForEach ($computer in $computername) 
{
    $Monitors = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID
$i = 1
Foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    $obj = new-object -type psobject
    $obj | Add-Member -Name ("Computername") -value $computer -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Modell") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.UserFriendlyName -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +" Serial") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.SerialNumberID -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $i++
    $items += $obj
}
    $obj2 = New-Object -type psobject
    $obj2 | Add-Member -Name ("Computername") -value $computer -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
    $obj2 | add-member -Name ("MAC-Addresse") -value $mac -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj2 | add-member -Name ("Seriennummer PC") -value $seriennummer_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force  
    $obj2 | add-member -Name ("Modell PC") -value $modell_pc -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj2 | add-member -Name ("IP Addresse") -value $ipv4 -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
}

$items | export-csv -path C:\Daten\Inventur\Bildschirm.csv -Append
$obj2 | export-csv -path C:\Daten\Inventur\Computer.csv -Append
```